# please explain while loop in the PERL code?

Tags: command-line, perl

This is some code to find word,chars,lines in a file. Can anyone please explain the while loop?

```
open(FILE, "<data.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);

while (<FILE>) {
    $lines++;
    $chars += length($_); //what _ stands for?
    $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_)); //what is /\s+/, $_
}

print("lines=$lines words=$words chars=$chars\n");
```

Comment: you forget to mentioned which code is this?

Comment: I would assume perl @AizuddinZali :)

Comment: its PERL code @AizuddinZali :

Comment: yes but `open` looks incomplete to me. i guess this is perl due to use of  `my` variable declaration.

Comment: now the code looks better :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<>` is the diamond operator. Using it in a while loop is the same as

```
while (defined($_ = readline FILE)) {
```

So, it reads the file line by line, assigning each line's contents to the topic variable `$_`.

The `++` operator adds one to a variable.

The `+=` operator adds the righthandside value to the lefthandside. [length](http://p3rl.org/length) returns length of a string.

[split](http://p3rl.org/split) splits the string on a regular expression. Here, `\s+` is used which means one or more whitespace characters. Calling [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) on the result returns the number of elements obtained.

Comment: $chars += length($_);
    $words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));               explain this please @aizuddin-zali

Comment: @pranav: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's Perl, (you should have made that clear).

Read `man perlintro`, which says, in part:

```
Files and I/O
   You can open a file for input or output using the "open()" function.
   It's documented in extravagant detail in perlfunc and perlopentut, but
   in short:

    open(my $in,  "<",  "input.txt")  or die "Can't open input.txt: $!";
    open(my $out, ">",  "output.txt") or die "Can't open output.txt: $!";
    open(my $log, ">>", "my.log")     or die "Can't open my.log: $!";

   You can read from an open filehandle using the "<>" operator.  In
   scalar context it reads a single line from the filehandle, and in list
   context it reads the whole file in, assigning each line to an element
   of the list:

    my $line  = <$in>;
    my @lines = <$in>;
```

If that's not enough, read `man perlfunc` and `man perlopentut`